# How to install DefiniteltyTyped for angular cli?

Tags: angular-cli

I installed https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/fhir and VSCode is able to resolve the package fine, however when I do `ng serve` it complains with:

> Cannot find namespace 'fhir'.

What could be the difference and how can I resolve it?

Comment: i guess you need to import it in your app.module

Comment: Importing was the hard bit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it sorted out with `import {} from '@types/fhir';`.